# Updating one column according to prediction on Shiny & rhandsontable

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

Hi I am trying to create a shiny app that serves users to update cells of a table. it's possible with rhandsontable, then in background, there is a model that predicts according to new updates on data and shows it as an extra column under the name of "Prediction" in the data.  I can easily build a dynamic data table with rhandsontable but cannot use it in real-time predicting. Here is what and how I tried.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    rHandsontableOutput("table"),
    plotOutput("plot1")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  mtcars %>%
  select(cyl,hp,carb,mpg) %>%
    head(10) -> data1
  model1 <- lm(mpg~cyl+hp+carb, data = data1)
  
  
  #colnames(data1)[4] <- "Prediction"

    output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data1) %>%
      hot_col("cyl", type = "dropdown", source = as.character(sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))), default = "4") %>%
      hot_col("hp", type = "dropdown", source = as.character(sort(unique(mtcars$hp))), default = "123") %>%
      hot_col("carb", type = "dropdown", source = as.character(sort(unique(mtcars$carb))), default = "2") %>% 
      hot_col('Prediction')
  })
  print(predict(model1,hot_to_r(input$table)))
  #preds<-predict(model1, hot_to_r(input$table))
  #data1$Prediction <- preds
  xax1<-1:10
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data3 <- hot_to_r(input$table)
    preds<-predict(model1, data3)
    #print(preds)
    #print("--------------------------")
    ggplot()+ geom_col(aes(x=xax1, y=preds))
    
    #plot(xax1, preds, type = "h", lwd=4)
  })
  
  

  

  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.